# How large is the current utxouts set

Tags: transactions, live-data

There was a website which shows statistics about the size of the set of all unspent transaction outputs. I can't find it any more.

Answer (score 2):

This information can be retrieved from a running node with the `getutxosetinfo` command.

```
 $ bitcoin-cli gettxoutsetinfo
{
  "height": 365344,
  "bestblock": "0000000000000000007c35a02dcbc73a0d10ef4cbaee9a597fe16208a828f451",
  "transactions": 6784625,
  "txouts": 25716140,
  "bytes_serialized": 877658065,
  "hash_serialized": "14bfa4c4aca29b11099b70deb76ee2e174524e70e8bb57addfa0ba17c3254804",
  "total_amount": 14383464.76669119
}
```

Note that "bytes serialized" is a measure of the *compressed* UTXO.

Answer (score 0):

[satoshi.info](http://statoshi.info/dashboard/db/unspent-transaction-output-set) has data about the unspent transaction outputs going back up to 30 days.